# How can I add outer markup to OBIE

Tags: oracle, obiee, oas

Good afternoon, I recently came across a problem in OBIE (OAS), namely, when marking up a table, I can’t add a border to the table borders, I poked everywhere but could not add it.

Is there any way to add a border to the table borders?

Have you ever encountered such a problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.